# v-bind:class and methods with some arguments

Tags: vue.js

Have the issue when I need to store selected option for some of list element, and changing it by click.

```html
    <template>
      <div class="poll-widget">
        <h2>Poll list</h2>
        <div class="poll-list">
          <div
            class="poll-list-item"
            v-bind:class="{'active':isActive(poll.name)}"
            v-on:click="onSelect(poll.name)"
            v-for="poll in pollList"
            :key="poll.id"
          >{{poll.name}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="poll-btn-block">
          <div class="poll-btn">Send</div>
          <div class="poll-btn">Results</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
```

```js
    <script>
    import { mapState } from "vuex";
    export default {
      name: "Poll",
      data: () => {
        return {
          selectedPoll: []
        };
      },
      methods: {
        onSelect: function(id) {
          this.selectedPoll[id].isChecked =  true ;
          console.log(this.selectedPoll);
        },
        isActive: function(id) {
          if (this.selectedPoll.indexOf(id) == -1) {
            this.selectedPoll[id] = { isChecked: false };
          } 
          console.log(this.selectedPoll[id].isChecked)
            return this.selectedPoll[id].isChecked;
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.$store.dispatch("loadPolls");
      },
      computed: {
        ...mapState(["pollList"])enter code here
      }
    };
    </script>
```

The problem comes when I click on some of `poll-list-item`.Changes doesn't effect.
`pollList` - loads from VUEX and it's ok, I don't want to keep changes there.

Comment: Please be more clear about your problem and if possible provide with a codesandbox live example of your problem.

Comment: @StarkButtowski isActive(poll.name) - method doesn't update changed status by calling onSelect(poll.name)

Comment: You have defined `selectedPoll` as array in data, but accessing everywhere as `object`. Try to confirm its type and access it in such way

Comment: @StarkButtowski  nope, doesn't work.Seems I can't use in v-bind:class function with parameters.I have idea comparing one selected option.But interesting is it right - that I can't using function with paremeters. In ReactJS it's possible.